Designing a buff/debuff system in a multiplayer game
I'm new to netcode and game dev and I'd like some input on a multiplayer buff/debuff system I'm working on in Unity, using NGO with a dedicated server. I aim to use a server authoritative architecture for my game, but I should mention I'm using a client transform component on player prefabs currently, so clients can execute movement commands without asking the server.
In my game, players pick a champion, and each champion has 4 unique abilities. Some abilities will grant a buff/debuff, currently I just have a single projectile ability which will only apply a debuff on the player that is hit by the projectile.
Champion, Ability and Buff are all classes. My main player script creates an instance of a Champion which has a list of 4 unique abilities (like Dota/LoL), some abilities have an instance of a Buff. An instance of a Buff has variables to store the total duration, current timer, effect type, effect strength and keypress (from linked ability).
Below is a diagram representing the current logic (note: the T(N) circles are not timesteps but identifiers for different steps in the logic):

Main concerns

RPC latency impacts buff timing. If the duration of a buff is set to 3 seconds, it will be cleared 100-200ms later, I could reduce every buff's duration by a similar amount to close the gap between the buff expiration time and when it clears from the player, is there a better way to handle this discrepency?
Purpose of a client side buff manager. I added the ClientBuffManager because it made sense at the time to record buffs locally for each player, but now I'm not sure if it's adding too much overhead. The benefits are that I have access to the buff timer locally and can use it for UI/VFX related things and it's easier to debug, the drawbacks are that it adds complexity and requires more RPCs. Whereas if I just use the NetworkBuffManager, it would only send an RPC to the client when a buff expires. Is the client side part redundant?
Client-Server desync, at step T4.5, if for whatever reason the server still thinks that the buff hasn't expired, but the client does, what should happen?

I'd appreciate any other advice about how a system like this should be implemented as I couldn't find any specific examples/resources of a system like this in a multiplayer context.

Wouldnt the 100-200ms latency affect all buffs/ debuffs equally? There should be no need to adjust it manually in the duration. And there might be always a case that someone has a bigger spike like 500ms+, you would not affect those as well. It should not matter if the local version of the buffs expires, are you planning on doing a visual fade out of the buffs? The dmg should be handled server side, as long as the buff duration there is applied correctly, you should be fine. And if you are totally insisting on accuracy, instead of time you could use stacks: next 3 attacks are buffed instead

Also if you are worried about buffs, how are you handling cooldown of spells? I would say this is a bigger issue if they appear ready on client side but are not yet on server side

It would affect them equally but buffs/debuffs each have a set duration, for example a slowness effect could be set to last for 3 seconds, if there's no adjustment, it will last for 3s + any RPC latency. Visually I'm only planning to show text/icon while a buff is applied

I handle cooldowns in basically the same way, but the RPC latency is less noticeable, I'll have a look at why that is

it will last for 3s + any RPC latency that is wrong. It will still last only 3sec, it might appear to last longer on client side but the true value is 3sec on your server. Else I could just manipulate the client and say: But hey, I have 2min latency, why is my berserker state already over? The buff will last 3sec from the moment the server registered the intention of casting the spell, not before and not longer

I find a lot of these challenges get easier when thinking of the game as though it were turn-based, with very fast auto-advancing turns. Each turn is one server update tick, and we can number those so all clients agree "this is what happened on turn 302". I can then schedule my buffs in these terms. "It's currently turn 305. I cast a buff, that will take effect on turn 315 and last until turn 415". The gap between now and effect start gives time for all peers to be notified and play the appropriate visuals/sound, and from then on everyone agrees whether the "now" turn is in the effect duration
